# VBA Code to Copy/Paste works only Temporarily

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My code loops through rows with data on one master-sheet and updates different sheets based on the category of the data on each row. When I run the macro, I can see the information temporarily flash where it should be pasted on the worksheet before disappearing. This does not happen where I have used the same copy/paste command before.

The beggining two loops with WOB and ROP will paste correctly while the custom loop does not. I have also tried making the Select Case into several elseif statements which has the same non-working result.

```
    Sub SortData()

Dim Datasheet As Worksheet
Dim ROPsheet As Worksheet 'Rate of Penetration
Dim Customsheet As Worksheet
Dim WOBsheet As Worksheet 'Weight on Bit

Dim i As Long 'Used as counter to loop through compiled data sheet
Dim j As Long 'Used as counter for each Limiter tested
Dim LastRowCount As Long 'Finds number of rows for ending loop

Dim Limiter As String 'These are WOB, ROP, Custom ect.
Dim DepthCheck As Double 'Checks depth on individual limiter sheet with depth on data sheet
Dim DatetCheck As String 'Checks date on individual limiter sheet with depth on data sheet
Dim Depth As Double 'depth from data sheet
Dim Datet As String 'date from limiter sheet

Dim y As Double 'Used to progress through rows

Set Datasheet = Worksheets("Data")
Set ROPsheet = Worksheets("ROP")
Set Customsheet = Worksheets("Custom")
Set WOBsheet = Worksheets("WOB")

y = 1
i = 1

'_____________________________________Working_Code_Below__________________________________________________________



'Arbitrary Count for testing
For i = 1 To 100

 y = y + 1

 Limiter = Worksheets("Data").Cells(y, 2).Value
 Depth = Worksheets("Data").Cells(y, 5).Value
 Datet = Worksheets("Data").Cells(y, 6).Value

'WOB
    If Limiter = "WOB" Then
      j = 1
      LastRowCount = WOBsheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Count

        For j = 1 To LastRowCount
         DepthCheck = Worksheets("WOB").Cells(j + 1, 5).Value
         DatetCheck = Worksheets("WOB").Cells(j + 1, 6).Value

            If DepthCheck <> Depth Or DatetCheck <> Datet Then
                 If j = LastRowCount Then
                         Datasheet.Range(Datasheet.Cells(y, 2), Datasheet.Cells(y, 13)).Copy Sheets("WOB").Cells(j + 1, 2)
                        GoTo EndLast
                 End If

            Else
                GoTo EndLast

            End If

        Next j

    Else
        GoTo ROPStart

    End If

ROPStart:


    If Limiter = "ROP" Then
      j = 1
      LastRowCount = ROPsheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Count

        For j = 1 To LastRowCount
         DepthCheck = Worksheets("ROP").Cells(j + 1, 5).Value
         DatetCheck = Worksheets("ROP").Cells(j + 1, 6).Value

            If DepthCheck <> Depth Or DatetCheck <> Datet Then
                 If j = LastRowCount Then
                         Datasheet.Range(Datasheet.Cells(y, 2), Datasheet.Cells(y, 13)).Copy Sheets("ROP").Cells(j + 1, 2)
                        GoTo EndLast
                 End If

            Else
                GoTo EndLast

            End If

        Next j

    Else
        GoTo CustomStart

    End If

CustomStart:

    j = 1
    LastRowCount = Customsheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Count

    Select Case Limiter

    Case "WOB", "Balling", "RPM", "Vibrations", "Torque", "Buckling", "Differential Pressure", "Flow Rate", "Pump Pressure", "Well Control", "Directional", "Logging", "ROP"
        GoTo EndLast

    Case Else
        For j = 1 To LastRowCount
            DepthCheck = Worksheets("Custom").Cells(j + 1, D).Value
            DatetCheck = Worksheets("Custom").Cells(j + 1, dt).Value

            If DepthCheck <> Depth Or DatetCheck <> Datet Then

                If j = LastRowCount Then
                    Datasheet.Range(Datasheet.Cells(y, 2), Datasheet.Cells(y, 13)).Copy Sheets("Custom").Cells(j + 1, 2)
                    GoTo EndLast
                End If

            Else
                GoTo EndLast

            End If

       Next j

   End Select

EndLast:

Next i
End Sub
```

No error messages appear.

PS. This is my first post so sorry if formatting is weird.

Comment: You don't need all those `GoTo EndLast` lines. The `Select` and `If`s control what gets executed or not. `GoTo` makes for spaghetti code.

Comment: Can you step through the code to see what is happening line by line? As @BigBen said it's pretty hard to read the code with all the goto statements. It looks like the first if statement will just exit the sub. Half the variables in this code are not defined in this snippet either, like ```y```.

Comment: Replace `GoTo EndLast` with `Exit Sub`.

Comment: I used the GoTo to stay within my main loop using i. Sorry for the confusion, I've added the rest of the code now to clarify it. Also, I have tried stepping through it and the first two loops will Copy/Paste but the third under custom will not.

Comment: Then replace `GoTo` with `Exit For`, and do yourself a favor and extract these inner blocks into their own parameterized procedure scopes, to reduce nesting and improve maintainability/readability. Goto-jumping should never be your *go-to* solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that to clean up the process! I have noticed that my "LastRowCount" does not actually work. Instead, I used:                                                                                                           LastRowCount = Customsheet.Cells.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row                                                                                                                                                                                            This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO and congratulations on your first post.  One of these days I'll be there with you, I'm just looking for the perfect question that's all.  Lack of courage has nothing to do with it, really, scout's honor.  Pinky promise!

I've tried following your code and struggle quite a bit because of the nonlinear flow.  The problem you describe sounds like the data is written and then overwritten.  This would typically be caused by a superfluous loop, in your case it may be induced by `GoTo`.

Touching on the comments about finding the row count; this is a surprisingly nuanced subject with many different answers and the correct one dependent on your circumstances and needs.  Most of the time I can use `UsedRange`, as in `Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count`; but I predominately work on spreadsheets I maintain and keep things as tight as my knowledge allows at the time.  I don't remember how long ago I bookmarked this website but I swear I used it daily for a couple months straight: [OZGrid Excel Ranges](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm)  And of course Chip Pearson is worth a call out [CPearson Last Used Cell](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LastCell.aspx)

Please take this last bit as constructive criticism and have a good laugh.  When you try to follow this code and get lost, take a step back, look at your code, and find the same pattern - and stop doing it.  Break the habit and break the habit hard.  Some people, myself included have a near visceral reaction when trying to debug spaghetti code. Try to write linearly top down.  You'll find that you understand your own code better, it's easier to keep track of your thoughts, and transfer those thoughts into code.  It's a win, win, win situation.  GoTo's are almost entirely unnecessary and really impede the progress of others trying to help; using one here or there can be a handy little shortcut in a 5 line function but are best avoided when your code requires scrolling.

```
Sub aProcedure()
    GoTo T
V:
    j = vbCancel
    b = "point"
    GoTo K
X2:
    j = x
    b = "before"
    GoTo K
A1:
    For i = VbMethod To vbCancel
        b = DoThingWith(DoThingWith(b, 44), b)
    Next
    j = j * 3
    a = DoThingWith(a, b)
    GoTo Z
Z:
    b = "times"
    GoTo K
U2:
    j = j + 1 - x
    b = "has"
    GoTo K
A2:
    MsgBox DoThingWith(a)
    Exit Sub
X1:
    j = j + 1
    b = "made"
    GoTo K
T:
    a = "this"
    GoTo U1
K:
    a = DoThingWith(a, b)
DoEvents
    Select Case j
        Case 0
            GoTo A2
        Case 1
            GoTo U1
        Case 2
            GoTo U2
        Case 3
            GoTo W
        Case 4
            GoTo X1
        Case 5
            GoTo Y
        Case Else
            GoTo X2
    End Select
W:
    j = 2 * (j - 1)
    b = "been"
    GoTo K
Y:
    b = "many"
    GoTo A1
U1:
    a = Replace(a, Left(a, 1), UCase(Left(a, 1)))
    GoTo V
End Sub

Private Function DoThingWith(a, Optional b = 46, Optional c = 32)
    If IsNumeric(b) Then
        b = CInt(b)
        c = CInt(c)
        Select Case Asc(Right(a, 1))
            Case b
                DoThingWith = a & Chr(b - c - 1)
            Case Else
                DoThingWith = a & Chr(b)
        End Select
    ElseIf IsNumeric(c) Then
        c = CInt(c)
        DoThingWith = a & Chr(c) & b
    Else
        DoThingWith = a & b & c
    End If
End Function
```

The output:

[image: Output]